# UnicodeEncodeError: surrogates not allowed pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, unicode, encoding

I have some chinese words in csv file. I through nifi ExecuteStreamCommand processor to input the csv file. And I get the UnicodeEncodeError: surrogates not allowed.

I know I can hardcode the field encode like `df['product']= df['product'].encode('utf-8', errors='surrogatepass')` . I tried this before and this is work.

But in this case, I don't know what csv file will input this python script in the future. So I can't hardcode.
I try to add errors='surrogatepass' in`df.to_csv` but still not work.

This is my code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3.6

import sys
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import io

df = pd.read_csv(sys.stdin)
df = df.drop_duplicates(
        subset=df.columns.difference(['keep']),keep = False)
df = df[(df.keep == '2')]
df.drop(['keep','df_cal'],axis = 1,inplace = True)

df.to_csv(sys.stdout,encoding='utf-8',errors='surrogatepass',index = None)
```

Is there a way for pandas to select all fields to encode?

Comment: Do you have example data? And are you sure the data is utf-8? It sounds like it could be UTF-16.

Comment: I am sure the data is utf-8 because I use Convert Character Set processor to change the data encode to be UTF-8. 
The example data:
```a,keep,df_cal
我愛你,1,222
你愛我,2,333
你愛我,2,333
你愛,2,333
```

Comment: This data doesn't trip the codec: `b''.join(c.encode('utf-8') for c in "a,keep,df_cal 我愛你,1,222 你愛我,2,333 你愛我,2,333 你愛,2,333").decode('utf-8')` works fine. What does your output look like when you use `replace` as an error handler? Is there any `b'\xef\xbf\xbd'` in there?